# Gulp: Did you forget to signal async completion?

Tags: gulp, npm

Я написал простенький таск и запустил его через консоль, но получил след. ошибку:
[image: Сам код]

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Картинки тяжелее читать и затем гуглить, переведите картинки в текст

Comment: Хорошо, возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gulp` требует флаг, который вернётся когда task завершится, но так как код может быть асинхронным ему требуются дополнительный помощник в определении завершении работы задачи.

Поэтому он передаёт функцию завершения в вашу задачу:

```
gulp.task('mytask', function(done) {
  console.log("Привет, я таск!");
  done();
});
```

Ещё можно вернуть `Promise`

```
gulp.task('mytask', function() { 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Привет, я таск!");
    resolve();
  });
});
```

тот же `Promise`, но через `async\await`:

```
gulp.task('mytask', async function() {
  console.log("Привет, я таск!");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помог!